# How to streaming video via VLC api in C#

Tags: c#, .net, video-streaming, vlc, libvlc

I'm working on small home project for video broadcasting. I've found some example [Example](http://csharpmagics.blogspot.com/), but it does not works, because needed old version of library 0.8.6. So I found it, but I have exceptions on unmanaged code when I've tried to get components from API. So maybe somebody works with VLC for videobrodcasting I would like if you are Advise any examples.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a solution and used [Vlc.DotNet](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet) wrapper
I've installed nuget packages and wrote console app:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Jman\VideoMaker.avi");

        var currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        // Default installation path of VideoLAN.LibVLC.Windows
        var libDirectory =
            new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "libvlc", IntPtr.Size == 4 ? "win-x86" : "win-x64"));

        using (var mediaPlayer = new Vlc.DotNet.Core.VlcMediaPlayer(libDirectory))
        {

            var mediaOptions = new[]
            {
                ":sout=#rtp{sdp=rtsp://192.168.1.162:8008/test}",
                ":sout-keep"
            };

            //mediaPlayer.SetMedia(new Uri("http://hls1.addictradio.net/addictrock_aac_hls/playlist.m3u8"),
            //    mediaOptions);

            mediaPlayer.SetMedia(file, mediaOptions);

            mediaPlayer.Play();

            Console.WriteLine("Streaming on rtsp://192.168.1.162:8008/test");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Then I ran VLC media player and entered my link. And I got my videostream

> rtsp://192.168.1.162:8008/test

You can look my test applications in my GitHub repository : [VideoBroadcast](https://github.com/Ledrunning/VideoBroadcast)